# I want to develop a basic Linux Terminal IM Client

Tags: python, instant-messaging

I'm a 19 years old guy with "basic" programming skills mostly on C and PHP.
I'm from Argentina, so sorry if i miss something in the grammar area.

Well, i would LOVE to expand my programming skills, but i need a project, because the challenges and exercises with no target don't enthusiast me. And reading about the programming language or how to focus this or that problem with no objective its useless.
So, i've been thinking in a project, nothing came to my mind that is not created yet, or it's to difficult to me, or something.

But i would like to start with a IM client that would run in a Linux terminal, and in a future when im comfortable with the protocols and that stuff, move it to a graphical environment in Linux or Windows OS.

For the terminal I'm thinking in something like Pebrot, simple and basic, but over LAN, so you could chat with people on your same workgroup, like i can ask my mom something in the other room, just basic, and just LAN, not outside my router.

In a future i would like to add to it a google talk client.

In the graphical area i would like to do the LAN client, but with popups and everything.

THE QUESTION IS.
If you could help me in the beginning of the project, because i don't know where to start.
I mean, what i need and what do you recommend.

Thank you.

Comment: Your grammar is fine, but you haven't really asked a programming question.

Comment: You mean like [Finch](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch)?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into socket programming with python as well as writing a simple client/server. Python is actually a very good language for this as it makes it easy to do socket programming. Much easier than, say, using C.

This is an excellent resource: http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyNet.pdf to get started.